# Can sharing sets be used for customer community plus licenses? What permissions are needed to create sharing sets?

Tags: community, licenses, customer-community, sharing-sets

I am trying to add sharing sets to a community with customer community plus license users.

When I try to add a new sharing set, I get the following error

> "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the
>   operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or
>   your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see
>   Insufficient Privileges Errors."

I have the system administrator profile (including the "Create and Set Up Communities" permission. Does anyone know what permission I am missing to be able to add a sharing set?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing sets are for the customer community (not plus), and other high-volume licenses where you can have millions of users but not "full" sharing rules.

CC+ has full sharing (rules, apex, and manual sharing), which allow way more than the more simplistic sharing sets.  The trade off is that that user count can't go above 350k or so--otherwise the sharing calculation has the potential to get ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Salesforce is working to hide the Related List if no licenses exist for the org.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=I-am-getting-an-Insufficient-Privileges-error-when-logged-in-as-a-System-Administrator-when-trying-to-create-a-sharing-set-in-a-Community&language=en_US